# Xcode Swift compile error import name too long

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

This is the error I'm getting from trying to build my project.

> `Opening import file for module 'Swift': File name too long`

This is the swift compile command being run:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/b7/c8z8dq8n6y5b1x29mx_p209w0000gn/T/sources-adfc78 -primary-file "/Users/james/Documents/workspace/fb-ios-recover/FitBugg/Model/Mock model/MockUser.swift" -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -I /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F " \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AFNetworking\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts-Swift\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HexColors\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQSystemSoundPlayer\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JTCalendar\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MBProgressHUD\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NMRangeSlider\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParseCrashReporting\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParseFacebookUtilsV4\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParseLiveQuery\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParseUI\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SocketRocket\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/THContactPicker\" \"/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TSMessages\" \"/Users/james/Documents/workspace/fb-ios-recover/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks\"" -enable-testing -g -import-objc-header /Users/james/Documents/workspace/fb-ios-recover/FitBugg-Bridging-Header.h -module-cache-path /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/FitBugg-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/FitBugg-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/FitBugg-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/FitBugg-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc "-I \"/Users/james/Documents/workspace/fb-ios-recover/Pods/Headers/Public\" \"/Users/james/Documents/workspace/fb-ios-recover/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps\"" -Xcc -I/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/james/Documents/workspace/fb-ios-recover -emit-module-doc-path /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MockUser~partial.swiftdoc -Onone -module-name FitBugg -emit-module-path /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MockUser~partial.swiftmodule -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MockUser.dia -emit-dependencies-path /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MockUser.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MockUser.swiftdeps -o /Users/james/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FitBugg-gzpxgbmtwqvbozdkgabiahuiovrr/Build/Intermediates/FitBugg.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FitBugg.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MockUser.o

Comment: Thanks for that Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at your logs I found strange all the `\"` after the `-F` option.

Could it be possible that in your build settings the *Framework search Paths* is set to `"$(inherited)"` instead of just `$(inherited)` (no surrounding `""`)?